# Create connection to SQL database using JDBC Driver- SQLException

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, tcp, connection

I am trying to connect SQL database to java. I added the driver jar from maven: `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:7.0.0.jre102`. I was using this sites to create a proper connection:

Implementing connection in java: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Creating a login to the database: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-2017

Enabling named pipes and TCP/IP connections: https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkenablenamedpipesandtcpipconnections.htm

But still- there is thrown an SQLException:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host LAPTOP-EG6DUP3O//LOCALDB#67B4CDC4, port 1433 has failed. Error: "LAPTOP-EG6DUP3O//LOCALDB#67B4CDC4. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Code of my tester class:

```
package main;
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-EG6DUP3O//LOCALDB#67B4CDC4:1433;" +
                "databaseName=TestBazyDanych;user=doszke;password=doszke123;";

        Connection con = null;

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(con != null){
            System.out.println("connected");
        } else {
            System.out.println("unable to connect");
        }

    }


}
```

I got one problem during TCP/IP connections setting. I cannot restart my server from SSMS and I did it via SQL Server Configuration Manager:
[image: SSMS- server cannot be restarted]

[image: Server restarted from SSCM]

Comment: The Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver cannot connect to a LocalDB, only to a real server.

Comment: Hmm, what could you recommend to use to connect to my local server?

Comment: You need to use the real server. I'd start with trying `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=TestBazyDanych`, then try with the port configured in the SQL Server setting of that host (`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestBazyDanych`) or start the SQL Server Browser service and use its instance name (`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\<instanceName>;databaseName=TestBazyDanych` (note the use of backslash instead of forward slash). But first of all, check your TCP/IP configuration. Default installations use a random port (if TCP/IP is enabled at all), not port 1433.

Comment: The second one worked for me fine, only an exception is thrown: login to database failed. But I think I can manage it. Thank you.